# What kind of algorithm would find a grid of squares in a reasonable time?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I found a result that there is a grid of size 9x13 with following properties:

Every cell contains a digit in base 10.

One can read the numbers from the grid by selecting a starting square, go to one of its 8 nearest grid, maintain that direction and concatenate numbers.

For example, if we have the following grid:

```
340934433
324324893
455423343
```

Then one can select the leftmost upper number 3 and select direction to the right and down to read numbers 3, 32 and 325.

Now one has to prove that there is a grid of size 9x13 where one can read the squares of 1 to 100, i.e. one can read all of the integers of the form i^2 where i=1,...,100 from the square.

The best grid I found on the net is of size 11x11, given in [Solving a recreational square packing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382859/solving-a-recreational-square-packing-problem) . But it looks like it is hard to modify the program to find integers in rectangular grid.

So what kind of algorithm would output a suitable grid in a reasonable time?

I just got a key error from this code:

```
import random, time, sys

N = 9
M = 13
K = 100

# These are the numbers we would like to pack
numbers = [str(i*i) for i in xrange(1, K+1)]

# Build the global list of digits (used for weighted random guess)
digits = "".join(numbers)

def random_digit(n=len(digits)-1):
    return digits[random.randint(0, n)]

# By how many lines each of the numbers is currently covered
count = dict((x, 0) for x in numbers)

# Number of actually covered numbers
covered = 0

# All lines in current position (row, cols, diags, counter-diags)
lines = (["*"*N for x in xrange(N)] +
         ["*"*M for x in xrange(M)] +
         ["*"*x for x in xrange(1, N)] + ["*"*x for x in xrange(N, 0, -1)] +
         ["*"*x for x in xrange(1, M)] + ["*"*x for x in xrange(M, 0, -1)])

# lines_of[x, y] -> list of line/char indexes
lines_of = {}
def add_line_of(x, y, L):
    try:
        lines_of[x, y].append(L)
    except KeyError:
        lines_of[x, y] = [L]
for y in xrange(N):
    for x in xrange(N):
        add_line_of(x, y, (y, x))
        add_line_of(x, y, (M + x, y))
        add_line_of(x, y, (2*M + (x + y), x - max(0, x + y - M + 1)))
        add_line_of(x, y, (2*M + 2*N-1 + (x + N-1 - y), x - max(0, x + (M-1 - y) - M + 1)))

# Numbers covered by each line
covered_numbers = [set() for x in xrange(len(lines))]

# Which numbers the string x covers
def cover(x):
    c = x + "/" + x[::-1]
    return [y for y in numbers if y in c]

# Set a matrix element
def setValue(x, y, d):
    global covered
    for i, j in lines_of[x, y]:
        L = lines[i]
        C = covered_numbers[i]
        newL = L[:j] + d + L[j+1:]
        newC = set(cover(newL))
        for lost in C - newC:
            count[lost] -= 1
            if count[lost] == 0:
                covered -= 1
        for gained in newC - C:
            count[gained] += 1
            if count[gained] == 1:
                covered += 1
        covered_numbers[i] = newC
        lines[i] = newL

def do_search(k, r):
    start = time.time()

    for i in xrange(r):
        x = random.randint(0, N-1)
        y = random.randint(0, M-1)
        setValue(x, y, random_digit())

    best = None
    attempts = k
    while attempts > 0:
        attempts -= 1
        old = []
        for ch in xrange(1):
            x = random.randint(0, N-1)
            y = random.randint(0, M-1)
            old.append((x, y, lines[y][x]))
            setValue(x, y, random_digit())
        if best is None or covered > best[0]:
            now = time.time()
            sys.stdout.write(str(covered) + chr(13))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            attempts = k
        if best is None or covered >= best[0]:
            best = [covered, lines[:N][:]]
        else:
            for x, y, o in old[::-1]:
                setValue(x, y, o)
    print
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return best

for y in xrange(N):
    for x in xrange(N):
        setValue(x, y, random_digit())

best = None
while True:
    if best is not None:
        for y in xrange(M):
            for x in xrange(N):
                setValue(x, y, best[1][y][x])
    x = do_search(100000, M)
    if best is None or x[0] > best[0]:
        print x[0]
        print "\n".join(" ".join(y) for y in x[1])
    if best is None or x[0] >= best[0]:
        best = x[:]
```

Comment: This is very unclear at the moment, here are a few things you should clarify. 1. Define what a grid of size 117 means. Does that mean it is 117 squares by 117 square or 117 squares total? 2. What does it mean to read the squares 1 to 100? From your example, you describe a system of reading a set of numbers, but not what it would mean to have all of the numbers 1 to 100. 3. Most importantly, what exactly is your question? Do you want us to write a program for you to find this? Have you already written it but it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I tried to write some code but I think it is not worth to implement it as my algorithms are too slow or takes too much memory.

Comment: Your edit helps to clarify somewhat but I think there are a couple typos, in one place you say `9x12` where it should say `9x13` and you list 10000 as one of the integers you care about, which is much outside the range of 1 to 100. You still haven't asked a clear and narrow enough question since "what kind of algorithm would solve this" is way too broad in my opinion since lots of algorithms could solve this. Additionally, I wanted to ask, where did you find "a result that there is a grid of size 9x13" with those properties? Did that source not say what that grid would be?

Comment: I just realized what you mean by finding all of the squares, you mean that you are trying to find all of the numbers `x` where `n^2 = x` where `n` is between 1 and 100. That was really confusing me before, thought that might just be because I'm slow

Comment: Also, what is the problem with the approach taken in the linked solution? It seems that it wouldn't actually be that hard to modify their solution to apply to non square grids

Comment: @KevinWells I tried to modify the source in a link but I'm just a junior programmer, I didn't managed to do that.

Comment: Alright, so then what do you want us to do about it? Is there something in particular you are having trouble adapting?

Comment: Also, I hope you don't think I'm being mean, I'm really trying to get this question into a form that can be answered well, I think it is an interesting problem

Comment: @KevinWells You are not mean. I have just so little experience on programming that I need some help. For me it is sometimes hard to write things clear enough.

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to determine if a grid (that the program does not create) has these properties, or are you asking for an algorithm to construct a grid that has these properties?

Comment: @MattJordan I'm asking an algoritm to construct a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create such a grid, I'd start with a list of strings representing the squares of the first K (100) numbers.

Reduce those strings as much as possible, where many are contained within others (for example, 625 contains 25, so 625 covers the squares of 5 and 25).

This should yield an initial list of 81 unique squares, requiring a minimum of about 312 digits:

```
def construct_optimal_set(K):
  # compute a minimal solution:
  numbers = [str(n*n) for n in range(0,K+1)]
  min_numbers = []
  # note: go in reverse direction, biggest to smallest, to maximize elimination of smaller numbers later
  while len(numbers) > 0:
    i = 0
    while i < len(min_numbers):
      q = min_numbers[i]
      qr = reverse(min_numbers[i])
      # check if the first number is contained within any element of min_numbers
      if numbers[-1] in q or numbers[-1] in qr:
        break
      # check if any element of min_numbers is contained within the first number
      elif q in numbers[-1] or qr in numbers[-1]:
        min_numbers[i] = numbers[-1]
        break
      i += 1
    # if not found, add it
    if i >= len(min_numbers):
      min_numbers.append(numbers[-1])
    numbers = numbers[:-1]
  min_numbers.sort()
  return min_numbers
```

This will return a minimal set of squares, with any squares that are subsets of other squares removed.  Extend this by concatenating any mostly-overlapping elements (such as 484 and 841 into 4841); I leave that as an exercise, since it will build familiarity with this code.

Then, you assemble these sort of like a cross-word puzzle.  As you assemble the values, pack based on probability of possible future overlaps, by computing a weight for each digit (for example, 1's are fairly common, 9's are less common, so given the choice, you would favor overlapping 9's rather than 1's).

Use something like the following code to build a list of all possible values that are represented in the current grid.  Use this periodically while building, in order to eliminate squares that are already represented, as well as to test whether your grid is a full solution.

```
def merge(digits):
  result = 0
  for i in range(len(digits)-1,-1,-1):
    result = result * 10 + digits[i]
  return result
def merge_reverse(digits):
  result = 0
  for i in range(0, len(digits)):
    result = result * 10 + digits[i]
  return result

# given a grid where each element contains a single numeric digit,
# return list of every ordering of those digits less than SQK,
# such that you pick a starting point and one of eight directions,
# and assemble digits until either end of grid or larger than SQK;
# this will construct only the unique combinations;
# also note that this will not construct a large number of values,
# since for any given direction, there are at most
#     (sqrt(n*n + m*m))!
# possible arrangements, and there will rarely be that many.
def construct_lines(grid, k):
  # rather than build a dictionary type, use a little more memory to use faster simple array indexes;
  # index is #, and value at index indicates existence: 0 = does not exist, >0 means exists in grid
  sqk = k*k
  combinations = [0]*(sqk+1)

  # do all horizontals, since they are easiest
  for y in range(len(grid)):
    digits = []
    for x in range(len(grid[y])):
      digits.append(grid[y][x])
      # for every possible starting point...
      for q in range(1,len(digits)):
        number = merge(digits[q:])
        if number <= sqk:
          combinations[number] += 1

  # now do all verticals
  # note that if the grid is really square, grid[0] will give an accurate width of all grid[y][] rows
  for x in range(len(grid[0])):
    digits = []
    for y in range(len(grid)):
      digits.append(grid[y][x])
      # for every possible starting point...
      for q in range(1,len(digits)):
        number = merge(digits[q:])
        if number <= sqk:
          combinations[number] += 1

  # the longer axis (x or y) in both directions will contain every possible diagonal
  # e.g. x is the longer axis here (using random characters to more easily distinguish idea):
  # [1 2 3 4]
  # [a b c d]
  # [. , $ !]
  # 'a,' can be obtained by reversing the diagonal starting on the bottom and working up and to the left
  # this means that every set must be reversed as well
  if len(grid) > len(grid[0]):

    # for each y, grab top and bottom in each of two diagonal directions, for a total of four sets,
    # and include the reverse of each set
    for y in range(len(grid)):

      digitsul = []  # origin point upper-left, heading down and right
      digitsur = []  # origin point upper-right, heading down and left
      digitsll = []  # origin point lower-left, heading up and right
      digitslr = []  # origin point lower-right, heading up and left

      revx = len(grid[y])-1 # pre-adjust this for computing reverse x coordinate

      for deltax in range(len(grid[y])):  # this may go off the grid, so check bounds
        if y+deltax < len(grid):
          digitsul.append(grid[y+deltax][deltax])
          digitsll.append(grid[y+deltax][revx - deltax])

          for q in range(1,len(digitsul)):
            number = merge(digitsul[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1
            number = merge_reverse(digitsul[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1

          for q in range(1,len(digitsll)):
            number = merge(digitsll[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1
            number = merge_reverse(digitsll[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1

        if y-deltax >= 0:
          digitsur.append(grid[y-deltax][deltax])
          digitslr.append(grid[y-deltax][revx - deltax])

          for q in range(1,len(digitsur)):
            number = merge(digitsur[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1
            number = merge_reverse(digitsur[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1

          for q in range(1,len(digitslr)):
            number = merge(digitslr[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1
            number = merge_reverse(digitslr[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1

  else:

    # for each x, ditto above
    for x in range(len(grid[0])):

      digitsul = []  # origin point upper-left, heading down and right
      digitsur = []  # origin point upper-right, heading down and left
      digitsll = []  # origin point lower-left, heading up and right
      digitslr = []  # origin point lower-right, heading up and left

      revy = len(grid)-1 # pre-adjust this for computing reverse y coordinate

      for deltay in range(len(grid)):  # this may go off the grid, so check bounds
        if x+deltay < len(grid[0]):
          digitsul.append(grid[deltay][x+deltay])
          digitsll.append(grid[revy - deltay][x+deltay])

          for q in range(1,len(digitsul)):
            number = merge(digitsul[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1
            number = merge_reverse(digitsul[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1

          for q in range(1,len(digitsll)):
            number = merge(digitsll[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1
            number = merge_reverse(digitsll[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1

        if x-deltay >= 0:
          digitsur.append(grid[deltay][x-deltay])
          digitslr.append(grid[revy - deltay][x - deltay])

          for q in range(1,len(digitsur)):
            number = merge(digitsur[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1
            number = merge_reverse(digitsur[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1

          for q in range(1,len(digitslr)):
            number = merge(digitslr[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1
            number = merge_reverse(digitslr[q:])
            if number <= sqk:
              combinations[number] += 1

  # now filter for squares only
  return [i for i in range(0,k+1) if combinations[i*i] > 0]
```

Constructing the grid will be computationally expensive overall, but you will only need to run the check function once for each possible placement, to select the best placement.

Optimize placement by finding the subset of overlapping areas where you can place a sequence of numbers - this should be tolerable in terms of time required, because you can cap the number of possible locations to check; e.g. you might cap it at 10 (again, find the optimal number experimentally), such that you test the first 10 possible placements against the function above to determine which placement, if any, adds the most possible squares.  As you progress, you will have fewer possible locations in which to insert the numbers, so testing which placement is best becomes computationally less expensive at the same time that your search for possible placements becomes more expensive, balancing out each other.

This will not handle all combinations, and will not pack as tightly as trying every possible arrangement and computing how many squares are covered, so some might be missed, but compared to O((N*M)!), this algorithm will actually complete in your lifetime (I'd actually estimate a few minutes on a decent computer - more if you parallelize the check for placement).

Comment: I guess you are right that this works but it looks like it is too complicated for me to implement the algorithm.

Comment: Is there a specific part that is a problem for you?  I don't think I will have time in the near future to create a full version, but I might be able to help on parts of it.

Comment: Nothing in particular but I just need more experience on coding to write the program.

Comment: You shouldn't reply to a bad quality question; this is of no value currently other than as a code writing service.