# Proving that a particular matrix exists

Tags: algorithm

I found this problem in a programming forum Ohjelmointiputka:

- https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/postit/tehtava.php?tunnus=ahdruu and
- https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/postit/tehtava.php?tunnus=ahdruu2

Somebody said that there is a solution found by a computer, but I was unable to find a proof.

Prove that there is a matrix with 117 elements containing the digits such that one can read the squares of the numbers 1, 2, ..., 100.

Here read means that you fix the starting position and direction (8 possibilities) and then go in that direction, concatenating the numbers. For example, if you can find for example the digits 1,0,0,0,0,4 consecutively, you have found the integer 100004, which contains the square numbers of 1, 2, 10, 100 and 20, since you can read off 1, 4, 100, 10000, and 400 (reversed) from that sequence.

But there are so many numbers to be found (100 square numbers, to be precise, or 81 if you remove those that are contained in another square number with total 312 digits) and so few integers in a matrix that you have to put all those square numbers so densely that finding such a matrix is difficult, at least for me.

I found that if there is such a matrix mxn, we may assume without loss of generalty that m<=n. Therefore, the matrix must be of the type `1x117`, `3x39` or `9x13`. But what kind of algorithm will find the matrix?

I have managed to do the program that checks if numbers to be added can be put on the board. But how can I implemented the searching algorithm?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Returns -1 if can not put and value how good a solution is if can be put. Bigger value of x is better.
def can_put_on_grid(grid, number, start_x, start_y, direction):
#   Check that the new number lies inside the grid.
    x = 0
    if start_x < 0 or start_x > len(grid[0]) - 1 or start_y < 0 or start_y > len(grid) - 1:
        return -1
    end = end_coordinates(number, start_x, start_y, direction)
    if end[0] < 0 or end[0] > len(grid[0]) - 1 or end[1] < 0 or end[1] > len(grid) - 1:
        return -1
#   Test if new number does not intersect any previous number.
    A = [-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1]
    B = [-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1]
    for i in range(0,len(number)):
        if grid[start_x + A[direction] * i][start_y + B[direction] * i] not in ("X", number[i]):
            return -1
        else:
            if grid[start_x + A[direction] * i][start_y + B[direction] * i] == number[i]:
                x += 1
    return x

def end_coordinates(number, start_x, start_y, direction):
    end_x = None
    end_y = None
    l = len(number)
    if direction in (1, 4, 7):
        end_x = start_x - l + 1
    if direction in (3, 6, 5):
        end_x = start_x + l - 1
    if direction in (2, 0):
        end_x = start_x
    if direction in (1, 2, 3):
        end_y = start_y - l + 1
    if direction in (7, 0, 5):
        end_y = start_y + l - 1
    if direction in (4, 6):
        end_y = start_y
    return (end_x, end_y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = [['X' for x in range(13)] for y in range(9)]
    numbers = [str(i*i) for i in range(1, 101)]
    directions = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    for i in directions:
        C = can_put_on_grid(A, "10000", 3, 5, i)
        if C > -1:
            print("One can put the number to the grid!")
    exit(0)
```

I also found think that brute force search or best first search is too slow. I think there might be a solution using simulated annealing, genetic algorithm or bin packing algorithm. I also wondered if one can apply Markov chains somehow to find the grid. Unfortunately those seems to be too hard for me to implemented at current skills.

Comment: This seems more math related than programming

Comment: @cricket_007 There is no more mathematics than computing squares. The hard part is to find an algorithm that finds the solution before the Sun burns all the computers and life on the Earth.

Comment: It could be enough to just express the constraints as a SAT instance and stuff the whole thing into a SAT solver.

Comment: @user2357112 I gave it a try, it takes so long that I wasn't patient enough for it to finish. Perhaps it will work better with a different encoding.. anyway I think there should be a cleverer way to do this

Comment: If you're looking specifically for an algorithm that can produce the 117 element solution, I'd be inclined to vote to close this as it's pretty much an under-specified reverse-engineering question (since you're asking how that one person managed to do it, assuming they didn't do it manually). If you're looking for an algorithm to produce the smallest possible matrix, I'd say competition-style questions are off topic (that *might* be on topic on [codegolf.se]).

Comment: This is not worth of closing. One can learn to make suitable algorithm by solving this question. I think it is nice to learn new things here.

Comment: At least that's assuming someone can't (1) come up with an algorithm to generate the matrix of minimum size in a reasonable amount of time and (2) prove that it's the minimum possible size. Is 117 the minimum possible size? I see nothing here or in the links indicating anything other than it being the size of a matrix some random person came up with.

Comment: I'm not asking a matrix with minimum size. I am asking a matrix with size 117. The person is not some random. It is the person behind the nickname jlaire.

Comment: @user2219896 you can use his identity as a hint, his github has a bunch of exact cover/dancing links repositories so that's probably how he did it.

Comment: @Dukeling There is the same problem already in code golf, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66417/finding-the-smallest-grid-of-squares

Answer (score 0):

There is a program for that in https://github.com/minkkilaukku/square-packing/blob/master/sqPackMB.py . Just change M=9, N=13 from the lines 20 and 21.